# How do you detect the PowerShell version from CMake?

Tags: powershell, cmake

I'm writing a program and am using CMake to create build files for Windows targets. My program calls a later version PowerShell using the popen() command, and I would like to detect in CMake what version of PowerShell running on the system when running CMake.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to invoke `popen` first with this command and then parse the output:

```
powershell -command "'{0}.{1}' -f $PSVersionTable[ 'PSVersion' ].Major, $PSVersionTable[ 'PSVersion' ].Minor"
```

This will return the `Major` and `Minor` properties of the version formatted as `<major>.<minor>`